# How to get lint support for MUI `sx` prop values

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, lint

I have tried the following approach, but I still don't get any lint support to detect erroneous style property and value.

```
import { SxProps, Theme } from "@mui/material";

export const navBarStyles: Record<string, SxProps<Theme> | undefined> = {
    notification: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        "&:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible": { backgroundColor: "white" }
    },
    test: {
        colorBlaBlaBla: 'greennnnn'
    }
}
```

In the above example, neither `colorBlaBlaBla` style property nor `greennnnn` value are throwing any lint warning in VSCode. I get autocomplete suggestion though. But is there a way to configure linter support for these wrong values in MUI `sx` prop?

Or should I use some other approach in MUI for getting linter support?

Answer (score 2):

Define your styles using TypeScript types and MUI's SxProps type. Create an interface for your styles like this:

```
import { SxProps, Theme } from "@mui/material";

interface NavBarStyles {
  notification: SxProps<Theme>;
  test: SxProps<Theme>;
}

export const navBarStyles: NavBarStyles = {
  notification: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    "&:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible": { backgroundColor: "white" }
  },
  test: {
    // TypeScript will provide autocompletion and linting for valid style properties and values
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
};
```

Now, TypeScript will provide autocompletion and linting for valid style properties and values when you use navBarStyles. If you try to use an invalid style property or value, TypeScript will show an error in your editor.

For example, if you attempt to use an invalid style property like colorBlaBlaBla or a value like greennnnn, TypeScript will highlight it as an error in your code editor, providing linting support.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on my side. You could have a look into this sandbox which reproduced my issue: `https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-artem-lsywdp?file=/Demo.tsx`

Comment: @SabbirAhmed The problem is that you are providing invalid CSS property names and values in your navBarStyles object. For example, "mango" and "greennnnn" are not valid CSS property values, and "backgroundColdfdfr" and "backgrounddfdfColo" are not valid CSS property names. TypeScript won't be able to catch these errors, the SxProps type only provides structural type checking.

To resolve this issue, you should provide valid CSS property names and values. If you have custom CSS properties or values that are not recognized by TypeScript, you can define them in a theme or use plain CSS classes.